# Image inside border

Tags: html, css

I created a triangle by using the following CSS code.

```
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;      
    border-top: 60px solid #000;
```

This border's background color is black as I mentioned #000 but now I need an image inside this triangle. I tried adding an other line to the CSS with background-image property but doing this is displaying full image in the square background not rectangle background.

How can I display the triangle with the image I need.

Comment: @John - Yeah, CSS. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this with pure CSS and work cross browser.  What you could do is have a masking image with a transparent triangle in the center placed over your other image.  If you make the sides appear to be the same color as your page it will give the illusion that the image is a triangle.

You could also use canvas and alter the image to make it a triangle.

In terms of CSS support, there are some mask settings.  For Safari and Chrome support only, you can use [-webkit-mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-webkit-mask).  For Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera you can use [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/mask).  There is no IE support though.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/9WdUc/) do?

Style sheet:

```
div {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;      
    border-top: 60px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
div::after {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/40/40/'); no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: -20px;    
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with leaving out non-WebKit supported browsers, try looking into masks with the -webkit-mask property so you can mask your image into a triangle.

Here's a good article on them: http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/